# Simple blinking box gif with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to make a blinking box with imagemagick

```
convert -loop 1 -delay 500 -dispose Background lightOn.png lightOff.png blink.gif
```

result is just the first image.

[image: light off is same image with %1 opacity]
[image: light on is the image with full opacity]
[image: result is a just light on]

Comment: It would help if you will provide your two input images. Have you tried setting -loop 0, so that it cycles multiple times? When I download your image, it is a PNG and not a GIF. Why is that?

Comment: figured it out, I think? gif format doesn't care about transparency or opacity. The first image was at 60% opacity, something that's lost in gif format. The more accurate way to describe what I was going for is an opaque-blinking-highlight box. Am I right about this?

Comment: GIF only knows about binary transparency -- fully transparent or fully opaque. It cannot handle partial transparency and will force it to one or the other binary values.